# To which class does this member function belong? OOP

Tags: c++, oop, language-agnostic

Let's say we're programming a simple poker game.

```
class Card
{
public:
    Card(Suit s, Rank r);
    enum Suit getSuit();
    enum Rank getRank();
    void printCard();
private:
    Suit suit;
    Rank rank;
};

class Deck
{
public:
    Deck();
    /* either friend class Dealer; or should Dealer's class function that 
    manipulates deck assigned here? or make private deck data public?? */
private:
    std::vector<Card> deck;
};

class Player
{
public:
    int raise();
    int bet();
    Card fold();
    void check();
private:
    Card hand;
    int money;
};

class Dealer
{
public:
    Dealer();
    void DealCardsToPlayers(Deck& d);
    void Shuffle(Deck& d);
    Player evaluateWinner();
private:
    int collectPot();
    int pot;
};
```

In real world, the deck itself wouldn't know what or how it should behave, and dealer will handle where and how the cards should behave. But I'm not sure if this is a good design in the programming world.

Where should the class function that manipulates Deck's data be?

Comment: what manipulated data are concerned ? cards on table or what ?

Comment: Personal opinion: If Deck is going to be a data member (i.e. component) of Dealer, then Deck declares dealer as a friend, and vice versa. If they aren't a data member of one another, then a third party should be responsible to transfer data between them.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd Generated instance of deck, which contains vector of 52 cards.

Comment: I'm not sure how your design looks like, but it seems to me `Deck` should have a public method `Card drawCard()`, which removes one card from `vector` and returns it. `Dealer` calls this method and passes the received `Card` to `Player`.

Comment: @JeremyHansen: as Yksisarvinen mentionned, it will depend on the design. I think that tou have to draw a little design of your program entities - relations - (compoisition/aggregaion) and tranform it using pointers or whatever and then it may be more clear.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: Only `Deck` should manipulate `Deck`. Only `Card` should manipulate `Card`. `Deck` contains `Card`s. `Dealer` has a  (contains) `Deck`. `Player` has a  (contains) `Hand` which contains `Card`s. `Ape` shall not kill `Ape`.

Comment: @user4581301 I figured that's the safest way, but In that case, that leads me to write Dealer's member function mostly behaving as invokers that spends most of their time calling functions from another class. Is there any downside to this if the program gets big enough? Or even if there is, making sure to encapsulate is a better tradeoff?

Comment: Yes, sometimes putting up walls and encapsulating everything has a cost, but I find that more often than not the price is worth it. When it isn't, then profile the code, find the most significant drag and consider rewriting it. My rule of thumb is start with the simplest to understand and implement and safest approach that can work and only make things hard when it's forced upon you. Unfortunately sometimes it's harder to find the simplest approach than the hardest.